# Delete array from array

Tags: python, numpy

I want to delete elements from array A that may be found in array B.

For example:

```
A = numpy.array([1, 5, 17, 28, 5])
B = numpy.array([3, 5])
C = numpy.delete(A, B)
```

> C= [1, 17, 28]

Comment: @Prune: Please don't dupe-close a NumPy-tagged question with a list question as the dupe target.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Numpy has a function for that :

```
numpy.setdiff1d(A, B)
```

That will give you a new array with the result you expect.

More info on the [sciPy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html)

Comment: Is numpy the fastest solution?

Comment: Sure is, numpy has C code running for most of its features.

Comment: Thanks Maxime. System does not let be accept an answer yet. Got to wait 5 minutes.

Comment: Note that `setdiff1d` will sort the result and remove duplicates. If you don't want that, `A[~numpy.isin(A, B)]` will avoid the sort and deduplication, as long as `A` is actually an array and not the list you put in the question.

Comment: While a lot of numpy code is compiled, that's not true for all.  You need to check the source to be sure.  In this case `setdiff1d` uses `np.unique` and `np.in1d` which turn have Python code.  It's heavily dependent on sorting.

Answer (score 7):

You can try :

```
list(set(A)-set(B))
#[1, 28, 17]
```

Or a list comprehension :

```
[a for a in A if a not in B]
```

Another solution :

```
import numpy 
A[~numpy.isin(A, B)]
#array([ 1, 17, 28])
```

Comment: Might want to point out the `set`-based solution does not necessarily preserve the order of the elements in `A`.

Answer (score 4):

Use a list-comprehension that iterates through `A` taking values that are not in `B`:

```
A = [1, 5, 17, 28, 5]
B = [3, 5]

print([x for x in A if x not in B])
# [1, 17, 28]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
numpy.array([e for e in A if not e in B])
```

Comment: that's just copy of previous answers and adds no value

Comment: Sorry, the other answers didn't load on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try :

```
V= [7,12,8,22,1]
N= [12,22,0,1,80,82,83,100,200,1000]
def test(array1, array2):
    A = array1
    B = array2
    c = []
    for a in range(len(A)):
        boolian=False
        for b in range(len(B)):
            if A[a]==B[b]:
                boolian=True
        if boolian==False:
            c.append(A[a])
    print(c)


test(V,N)
```